# Vue: empty array automatically populated with Observer object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to init an empty array in the data and then get a JSON from the server and populate it.

The problem is that the array always have an extra Observer object so when i log it i see this:

> empty items array: [**ob**: Observer]

here is a code excerpt:

```
data() {
        return {
            items: []
        }
    },
 created() {
         this.$http.get('/api/menus').then(function (response) {

            console.log('items before', this.items); //THIS LOGS items before: [__ob__: Observer]
             this.items = [].concat(response.body);
            this.items.forEach(function (item) {
              console.log('item', item);

              item.$add('active', false);

              item.tests.forEach(function (test) {
                  test.$add('active', false);
              });
        });

         }).catch(function (err) {
             console.error('err', err);

         });

     },
```

The problem is that when trying to add a new property to the objects in the array i get an error:

> err TypeError: item.$add is not a function

when i debug i see it happens because it considers the observer object as part of the array.

Is it normal? should i just check if $add exists? what about when rendering it in the view, does Vue ignore this object?

Comment: I think this is normal, because VueJS use observers for reactivity, so each item in data object has attached observer.Check this but with Browser Console, not using the JsBin http://jsbin.com/qusugoyame/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Yes, all correct, and what is the problem though?

Comment: What should be $add method ? It depracated use $set

Comment: @BelminBedak I get the same with $set

Comment: Because you are using it wrong its instance method that accept 3 params obj, key, value.It could be used globally as Vue.set and in instance as alias as this.$set. I am on mobile now when I got home I will provide full answer if someone else doesnt provide it until that

Comment: Here is the working example http://jsbin.com/qusugoyame/edit?html,js,console,output - let me know are you looking for this so I can explain it and add as answer

Comment: @BelminBedak - thanks, your example helped me, I've already noticed that i needed to add the object when using the set, but it still didn't work, only when i used arrow function and `this` it worked.

Comment: Yeah using arrow function sometimes could solve context issue depending on situation.@GONG provided good answer so you can accept it, there are no need to post mine one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to your code, you want to set `active` property in your `items` object to `false`. Also you want to set all the properties `active` in every item's `tests` property to `false`.

Vue.js is reactive and detect changes automatically, but only for objects themselves, not their properties. For array vue will only detect changes by those methods (more about list rendering in vue.js https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#ad):

- push()
- pop()
- shift()
- unshift()
- splice()
- sort()
- reverse()

But how about properties? You can `force` vue to see change in deep of array or object with `Vue.set(object, property, value)` or `this.$set` in any `Vue` instance.

So, in your example you can implement it like this:

```
this.items.forEach(function (item, key) {
    console.log('item', item);

    this.$set(this.items[key], 'active', false);

    item.tests.forEach(function (test, testKey) {
        this.$set(this.items[key].tests[testKey], 'active', false);
    }, this);
}, this);
```

And it should work. Here is working example: http://jsbin.com/cegafiqeyi/edit?html,js,output (some ES6 features used, don't be confused)

Comment: This way your losing `this` context. Editing.

Comment: @JonatasWalker oh, yes, sorry, it's all ES6